# sed command giving error

Tags: shell-script

I have some files with format `c1234.$pid.$date`

I want to get the pid from this. What I do is write all these filenames to a
result file and do

```
cat result.$$ | for x in `sed -e 's/..*8\.//g'`
```

But I am getting error as

```
syntax error at line 12 : ``' unmatched
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: The error might be somewhere else in your script before this line. You should show your complete script. If you want to process the lines in `result.$$` one by one you should better use something like `sed -e 's/..*8\.//g' result.$$ | while read -r x; do something ; done`. see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 0):

You can list the files and run a for loop over them and pull out the $pid in each iteration.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Go to the path where files are present
cd /path/to files
# Initiate a for loop
for file in `ls`
do
    #Use '.' as a field separator and pull out the second column.
    cat "$file" | awk -F'.' '{print $2}'
done
```

Comment: Here, If i want to get files based on pid and date and compress those are older than a day,
I wrote command like below:

find $path -name c1234.*[0-9].$day -ctime +0 where day=`date +%Y%m%d` >/tmp/result.$$
cat /tmp/result.$$ | for x in `sed -e 's/..*8\.//g'`
do
    ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $x  >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        compress -f $path/log/c01808.$x
    fi
done

Unfortunately, it is not working. Why?